# Movable image within a circle

Tags: android, android-layout, crop

[image]

In this image, circle is static one. Rectangle image is in behind of this circle. I need to move,zoom out, zoom in and pan the rectangle image within this circle. How to achieve this?

Give me suggestions how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give me suggestions than put down vote brothers. I will correct my mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the Guidelines to do so:

1. Take Relative Layout
2. Add ImageView in This layout.
3. Now add Circle Shape Image in it.

example:

```
      <RelativeLayout>
         <ImageView /> // image which have to apply movement.
         <ImaeView />  // circle shape
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Then Apply below code to use movement of Imageview.

Implements Activity with OnTouchListener, Then

```
         img.setonTouchListener(this);



         @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     view= (ImageView) v;


        // make the image scalable as a matrix
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        float scale;

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
           savedMatrix.set(matrix);
           start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
           Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
           mode = DRAG;
           break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted
           mode = NONE;
           Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
           break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger down
           oldDist = spacing(event); // calculates the distance between two points where user touched.
           Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
           // minimal distance between both the fingers
           if (oldDist > 5f) {
              savedMatrix.set(matrix);
              midPoint(mid, event); // sets the mid-point of the straight line between two points where user touched. 
              mode = ZOOM;
              Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
           }
           break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
           if (mode == DRAG) 
           { //movement of first finger
              matrix.set(savedMatrix);
              if (view.getLeft() >= -392)
              {
                 matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
              }
           }
           else if (mode == ZOOM) { //pinch zooming
              float newDist = spacing(event);
              Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
              if (newDist > 5f) {
                 matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                 scale = newDist/oldDist; //thinking I need to play around with this value to limit it**
                 matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
              }
           }
           break;
        }

        // Perform the transformation
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

        return true; // indicate event was handled
     }

     private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
     }

     private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
     }
```

Hope this will help you, Its easy Task.

Comment: Thanks balvinder !.. This is what i need.

Comment: but if we use the only ring shape image at that time the corner of imageview  which is behind on rounded imageview ,it is also display outside the circle,then what we have to do?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at

[TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

you can zoom and pan the imageview using class

Answer (score 0):

This library exactly does this [ProfileView](https://github.com/KaveriKR/ProfileView).

It has a customizable circular view with an `imageview` with in it , that is scalable,  movable and  these events customized.